# Como adicionar twitter-bootstrap em um projeto symfony 2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony-2

Criei um projeto symfony 2, agora quero incluir o twitter-bootstrap nesse projeto. Como fazer essa inclusão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nunca trabalhei com Symfony, mas o jeito fácil - que vale para qualquer framework - é usar CDN.

Inclua o seguinte no `<head>` do seu HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

O Javascript é opcional, dependendo da sua necessidade:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma Bundle que fornece serviços, template tags que integram com o twitter dentre outras coisas que facilitam a integração do bootstrap no seu projeto: http://bootstrap1.braincrafted.com/

Mas só pra esclarecer são duas coisas distintas, o bootstrap é uma biblioteca CSS[/Javascript] que pode ser integrado a qualquer projeto, seja ele Symfony ou não, vc pode integrar baixando diretamente os aquivos fontes como citado na resposta acima..